# InvocationTargetException with Android Studio Arctic Fox on M1 Apple silicon

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to build an android project on apple silicon with Android studio Artic Fox. [image]

But Project is not building. I tried like hundred times changing the room version but its not working. Here are the dependencies I am using so far:

```
minSdkVersion = 21
targetSdkVersion = 30
compileSdkVersion = 30
testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

kotlinVersion = '1.5.30'
nstack_version = '3.2.8'

// Library versions
dagger_version = '2.29.1'
leak_canary_version = '1.6.3'
okhttp_version = '4.9.0'
moshi_version = '1.11.0'
retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
room_version = '2.4.0-alpha04'
work_version = '2.4.0'
navigation_version = '2.3.1'
glide_version = '4.11.0'
billing_version = '3.0.1'
coroutines_version = '1.5.2'
exoplayer_version = '2.14.0'

// Library implementations
androidxCore = "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1"
androidxCoreRuntime = "androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0"
androidxAnnotations = "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
androidxSecurity = "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc03"
androidxExifInterface = "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.2.0"
androidxPreference = "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"

// Work manager
workManagerKtx = "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
workManagerRx = "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version"
// Test helpers
workManagerTesting = "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"

// Coroutines
coroutinesCore = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
coroutinesAndroid = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
coroutinesTest = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_version"

// RX
rx = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19"
rxAndroid = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
rxKotlin = 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0'
rxLint = 'nl.littlerobots.rxlint:rxlint:1.7.5'

// Network
okhttp = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
okhttpLoggingInterceptor = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"

retrofit = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
retrofitRx = "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"
retrofitGson = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

moshi = "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshi_version"
moshiCodegen = "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version"
moshiAdapters = "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:$moshi_version"
retrofitMoshi = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"

// Room
room = "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
roomCompiler = "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
roomRx = "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version" // optional - RxJava support for Room
roomCo = "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
roomTesting = "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version" // Test helpers

// Dagger
dagger = "com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger_version}"
daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${dagger_version}"
daggerAnnotation = 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

// Dates and time
threetenabp = 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.4'
threetenabpTest = 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.4.5'

// Utilities
aTool = 'dk.eleknet.git.elek:aTool:1.1.0'
gson = 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

//--- Testing ---//
androidTestRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

// Versions
junit_version = '4.12'
mockito_version = '3.2.4'
hamcrest_version = '1.3'
test_runner_version = '1.2.0'
espresso_version = '3.2.0'


// Libraries
junit = "junit:junit:${junit_version}"
mockitoCore = "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockito_version}"
hamcrest = "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:${hamcrest_version}"
mockitoKotlin = "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"

androidxTestRules = "androidx.test:rules:$test_runner_version"
androidxJunit = "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1"
espressoCore = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
espressoIntents = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso_version"
espressoContrib = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso_version"

mockitoAndroid = "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito_version"
coreTesting = "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1"
mockWebserver = "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$okhttp_version"

workTesting = "android.arch.work:work-testing:$work_version"

androidxOrchestrator = "androidx.test:orchestrator:$test_runner_version"

// Exoplayer
exoplayerCore = "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:${exoplayer_version}"
exoplayerUi = "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:${exoplayer_version}"
exoPlayerExtentsionCast = "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:${exoplayer_version}"
exoPlayerExtentsionMediaSession = "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:${exoplayer_version}"
```

Here is my project level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"

buildscript {
    apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "dk.nodes.nstack:translation:$nstack_version"
        classpath "dk.nodes.ci:bitrise:1.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.2'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_version"
        classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.33.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply from: "$rootDir/code-check/ktlint.gradle"
    apply from: "$rootDir/code-check/detekt.gradle"

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://mobilesdk.useinsider.com/android" }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        project.apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
        dependencyUpdates.resolutionStrategy {
            componentSelection { rules ->
                rules.all { ComponentSelection selection ->
                    boolean rejected = ['alpha', 'beta', 'rc', 'cr', 'm', 'preview', 'b', 'ea'].any { qualifier ->
                        selection.candidate.version ==~ /(?i).*[.-]$qualifier[.\d-+]*/
                    }
                    if (rejected) {
                        selection.reject('Release candidate')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

The exception I am getting right now is this:

```
Execution failed for task ':data:kaptProdDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights
```

What can I do to build successfully this project on apple silicon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below dependencies I was able to build project successfully:

```
kotlinVersion = '1.4.20'
nstack_version = '3.2.8'

// Library versions
dagger_version = '2.29.1'
leak_canary_version = '1.6.3'
okhttp_version = '4.9.0'
moshi_version = '1.11.0'
retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
room_version = '2.4.0-alpha04'
work_version = '2.4.0'
navigation_version = '2.3.1'
glide_version = '4.11.0'
billing_version = '3.0.1'
coroutines_version = '1.4.3'
exoplayer_version = '2.14.0'
```

Comment: So, What's wrong there? What cause of your issue @Istak Morsalin?

Comment: kotlin version + room_version